# Excel - Compute number of people by group

Tags: excel

I have a table in Excel.
I would like to know if among a group ("Fruits") every fruit type was planted by the same person or not.

For example, in the following table, all apricots and blueberries were planted by the same people while strawberries were planted by different people.

```
Fruit        Planted by   Day
Apricots     Amanda       01/07
Apricots     Amanda       02/07
Apricots     Amanda       03/07
Strawberries Kevin        01/07
Strawberries Amanda       01/07
Blueberries  Emily        02/07
Blueberries  Emily        03/07
```

So I would like a case like this at the end:

```
Who             Number of plantation
Only Amanda      1
Only Kevin       0
Only Emily       1
Amanda and Kevin 1
Amanda and Emily 0
Kevin and Emily  0
```

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Imagine you have 10 people, that would lead to a list of 1022 combinations (Only ..., ... and ..., ... and ... and ..., ...), is this really what you want?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS()`.

Comment: @Dominique, Yes, I know that I only have 4 Different groups and that will not change. And I am not interested in every combination.

Comment: Thank you @Harun24HR but this is not what I want. I do not think ```COUNTIFS()``` may help me on this matter because the number of different fruits I have is very high (about 2000) so I cannot do a simple ```COUNTIFS()```.

Comment: @Emeline How only Kevin is `0` while he planted `Strawberries`?

Comment: @Harun24HR Sorry if I was not clear. It is because he did not do it alone, so I cannot count him in "Only Kevin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the pivot table below can help you.  You will see more than one record for each fruit, if a fruit planted by two or more.

[image] .

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what I want. But I do not want to edit it when I do a modification... :-/